# Running a separate thread, updating the UI and being able to cancel it

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I have a Windows Forms application that runs a process that takes up to 3 hours to complete.  While it is running I would like the UI to be responsive to 'Stop' commands and also to update on the progress of the job.  In simple terms the long running task is going around a loop thousands of times processing records and it's within this loop that I would like to update the UI.

I have managed to get code running using the FromCurrentSynchronizationContext option with TPL Tasks.  I have also used CancellationTokens to cancel a running thread.

However I cannot work out how to combine the two.

Comment: The BackgroundWorker is designed with exactly this in mind: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx The example looks to be almost exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by *"combine the two"*? If you have a cancellation token you simply pass that in with the task and internally check the state.

Comment: use BackgroundWorker. have a look at its events and properties, it can report progress which you can use to update the progress on UI. It also supports cancellation.

Comment: Does this mean you have a windows application that starts another process and that second process does the work? Or do you have one process with two threads?

Comment: Use a `BackgroundWorker` and `Runasync` then `Invoke` the UI changes from within the `BackgroundWorker`.  To Cancel it just use `Cancelasync` on it

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by *"combine the two"* but here is a very simple example of a long running task with cancellation support which updates a UI component after each iteration

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;

Task.Run(() => 
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300); // simulate work
        // check if the task has been cancelled and throw if required
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        // otherwise update the UI
        someTextBox.Invoke(() => someTextBox.Text = String.Format("Iteration: {0}", i));
    }
}
, token);
// cancel the task after 5 seconds
Task.Run(async delegate 
{
    await Task.Delay(5000); 
    tokenSource.Cancel(); 
});
```

Comment: Task.Run I believe is .Net 4.5 what would the equivalent be in .Net 4.0.

Comment: @user3324178 Task.Factory.StartNew